# How to get Split string in different array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I want to get input from user and if find `space` put the first string in array and second string in another new array such as when the user input is `first second third` i want to save `first` in char array and `second` in another char array. I write this code to split but don't know how to save input in array and the number of arrays such as number of spaces.

```
s = Console.ReadLine();
string[] ssize = s.Split(null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing in the right way already.

```
s = Console.ReadLine();
//User inputs "First Second Third"
string[] ssize = s.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string str in ssize)
   Console.WriteLine("string: {0}", str);
```

or

```
s = Console.ReadLine();
//User inputs "First Second Third"
string[] ssize = s.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for(int i = 0; i < ssize .Length; i++)
   Console.WriteLine("string {0}: {1}", i+1, ssize [i]);
```

ssize is an array and each element will contain one string.

See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for help, how can i pass each array to function to do some operation in it and if find space give me new line, I already pass it but function still read it as one array

Comment: I think this is another question and the best is to ask as a new question. BUT... It seems that you could use some formation on C#. There are lots of tutorials on the net (ex. look on google for "C# tutorial" and "C# course"). To pass each STRING found separately, just use the for or foreach that I showed calling the function passing the string (as in the Console.WriteLine call). But I strongly recommend you to read more on C# before asking again, or at least, ask a new question with the new problem with more details.

Answer (score 1):

A string can be accessed as if it is a char array so if you do the following:

```
var s = "one two three";
string[] ssize = s.Split(' ');
var myChar = ssize[0][0];
```

then `myChar` will be `o`;

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
var s = "first second third";
var words = s.Split(' ');
var charArrays = words.ToList().ConvertAll(x => x.ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to store the strings in char arrays: just call ToCharArray on each string in the ssize array when you need to get the char array.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
string[] ssize = s.Split(' ');
```

The number of words entered is given by

```
ssize.Length
```

To access single characters you can use the indexing operator of the strings directly:

```
char firstCharOfFirstWord = sstring[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s.Split(' ').Select(p=>p.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
```